# how to extract attribute value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble extracting "href" value of "LINE_NAME" (expected value is "www.link.com"). 
It's a content of a table which always has only header + 1 row, column order and number can be different though. "LINE_NAME" column is always there in the exact format

this call returns "undefined":

```js
var url = $('.a-IRR-table tbody').children().eq(2).find('td[headers="LINE_NAME"] a').attr('href');

console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table summary="Search Results" class="a-IRR-table" id="79" style="margin-top: -45px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="a-IRR-header"><a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="625" role="presentation">Av</a>
        <div class="t-fht-line"></div>
      </th>
      <th class="a-IRR-header"><a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="437" role="presentation">CS</a>
        <div class="t-fht-line"></div>
      </th>
      <th class="a-IRR-header"><a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="167" role="presentation">LINE_NAME</a>
        <div class="t-fht-line"></div>
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td class=" u-tC" headers="AVAILABLE" aria-labelledby="AVAILABLE">
          <img src="...png" alt="Av_ICON" title="Available" style="width:16px; padding-top:1px;">
        </td>
        <td class=" u-tL" headers="STATUS" aria-labelledby="STATUS">online</td>
        <td class=" u-tL" headers="LINE_NAME" aria-labelledby="LINE_NAME">
          <a href="www.link.com">url_link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The argument given to `.eq()` is zero-based, so I guess you want `eq(1)` instead of `eq(2)`.

Comment: Just remove .children() and .eq alltogether: $('.a-IRR-table tbody').find('td[headers="LINE_NAME"] a').attr('href'); or $('.a-IRR-table td[headers="LINE_NAME a').attr('href');

Comment: And remove find.... `$('.a-IRR-table tbody td[headers="LINE_NAME"] a')`

Comment: and simplify to.. `$('.a-IRR-table td[headers="LINE_NAME"] a').attr('href')`

Comment: thanks guys for such a lighting response. Not sure how could I miss the numbering, stupid mistake :) appreciate simplified and cleaner calls!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `.eq()` function from [jQuery is 0 based](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), so to get the 2nd element you have to use `.eq(1)`.

```js
var url = $('.a-IRR-table tbody').children().eq(1).find('td[headers="LINE_NAME"] a').attr('href');
console.log(url)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table summary="Search Results" class="a-IRR-table" id="79">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th class="a-IRR-header"><a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="625" role="presentation">Av</a><div class="t-fht-line"></div></th>
   <th class="a-IRR-header"><a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="437" role="presentation">CS</a><div class="t-fht-line"></div></th>
   <th class="a-IRR-header"><a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="167" role="presentation">LINE_NAME</a><div class="t-fht-line"></div></th>
  <tr>
   <td class=" u-tC" headers="AVAILABLE" aria-labelledby="AVAILABLE">
    <img src="...png" alt="Av_ICON" title="Available" style="width:16px; padding-top:1px;">
    </td>
   <td class=" u-tL" headers="STATUS" aria-labelledby="STATUS">online</td>
   <td class=" u-tL" headers="LINE_NAME" aria-labelledby="LINE_NAME">
    <a href="www.link.com">url_link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = $('.a-IRR-table').find('td[headers="LINE_NAME"] a').attr('href');

console.log('url = ' + url);
```

should work